# How do I prevent multiple results when condition is null for a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

Assuming the following two SQL tables.

**db.Fruits**

```
ID  Name
F1  Apple
F2  Orange
F3  Melon
```

**db.Attributes**

```
ID  Fruits_ID   AttributeType   AttributeValue
A1  F1          Color           Red
A2  F3          Size            Large
A3  F2          Size            Small
A4  F1          Size            Small
A6  F3          Color           Brown
```

How do I use a LINQ query to search for the fruit I want with multiple nullable conditions WITHOUT multiplying the results due to a JOIN? For example, the following query produces multiple results if `condition` is null.

```
var q = from f in db.Fruits
        join a in db.Attributes
        on f.ID equals a.Fruits_ID
        where string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition) || fa.AttributeValue.Contains(conditon)
        select FruitResult
        {
            // ...
        }
```

In any case, I have also looked into `INTO` but that's not working for me.

```
var q = from f in db.Fruits
        join a in db.Attributes
        on f.ID equals a.Fruits_ID
        into FruitsAttributes

        from fa in FruitsAttributes
        where string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition) || fa.AttributeValue.Contains(conditon)
        select FruitResult
        {
            // ...
        }
```

The above still returns multiple/joined results when `condition` is null or empty.

**TL;DR:** How do I use a one-to-many `.Contains` check in my query such that, if the conditions are null, returns individual "unjoined" rows?

Comment: I am not quite sure what should be `condition`. i think you should union 2 queries, one for the `condition != null` and one query without join with `condition == null`. For example 
`var q1 = from f in db.Fruits
        join a in db.Attributes
        on f.ID equals a.Fruits_ID
        where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition) || fa.AttributeValue.Contains(conditon)
        select FruitResult        {            // ...        };
var q2 = from f in db.Fruits
        where string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition)
        select FruitResult        {            // ...        };
var q = q1.Union(q2);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally arrived at an answer. It's actually very simple, just had to create a filter and skip the join.

```
var qFilter = from a in db.Attributes
              where a.AttributeValue.Contains(condition)
              select a.Fruits_ID

var q = from f in db.Fruits
        where string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition) || qFilter.Contains(f.ID)
        select FruitResult
        {
            // ...
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
var q = from f in db.Fruits
                join a in db.Attributes
                on f.Id equals a.FruitId
                into g
                select new FruitResult
                {
                    Id = f.Id,
                    Name = f.Name,
                    Attribute = condition != null ? g.FirstOrDefault(a => a.AttributeValue.Contains(condition)) : null
                };
```

You can easily extend retrievieng Attribute value in the select, I don't know what you need, so I left it as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're expecting an empty set if `condition` is null since it won't match any attributes? The easiest way would be to just handle that case separately.

```
IEnumerable<FruitResult> q;
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(condition))
{
    q = from f in db.Fruits
        join a in db.Attributes
        on f.ID equals a.Fruits_ID
        where fa.AttributeValue.Contains(conditon)
        select FruitResult
        {
            // ...
        }
}
else
{
    q = Enumberable.Empty<FruitResult>();
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's the opposite. Condition being blank should act like a catch-all, i.e. return all the rows. What I'm trying here is to avoid returning multiple rows due to the joining.